# ios - downloading an image with oauth access token

Tags: ios, oauth, uiimageview, access-token

In iOS, I am trying to download an image but I need to pass in an access token. Usually, I download the image with this code (disregar:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSString *curURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myBaseURL.com/img.png"];
        NSLog(@"cur url: %@", curURL);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:curURL]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.propImg1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [self.propImg1 setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or better yet example code on how to pass in the access token?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NSURLConnection` for this. You can still do with this one liner `dataWithContentsOfURL` . Check [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/security/a-simple-way-to-download-data-from-a-password-protected-web-page).

Comment: I need to use the oauth token though, not a username and password.